# R: Creating new variables in a for loop and assign values

Tags: r, assign

I would like to create a new variable, assign a list of values, and write into a hierarchical data frame. I tried the below but it is not writing in.

```
for(i in 1:sample){
    for(j in 1:10){
      x[,j]<-0
      name <- paste("hierdata[[i]]$Test", j, sep = "_")
      assign(name, rowSums(alpha+beta+x)))
    }
}
```

Appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have a reprex data sample please? Preferably with dput.

Comment: using nested for loops is usually bad practice, growing a data frame is usually bad practice, using code stored into strings is usually bad practice, and using assign is usually bad practice :). If you provide a reproductible example I'm sure someone will be happy to provide you a nice one liner full of good practice ;).

Answer (score 0):

**To address @Moody_Mudskipper 's comment:**

The best way to declare hierarchical data is to use indexed lists:

```
hierdata <- lapply(1:sample,
       function(iterator)
         {
         temp_list <- lapply(1:10,
                function(j)
                  {
                  x[,j]<-0
                  value <- rowSums(alpha+beta+x)
                  return(value)
                })
         names(temp_list) <- lapply(1:10,function(j){paste0("temp_",j)})
         return(temp_list)
       })
```

not really a "one liner", but it contains all good "stuff". Lapply which returns list by default so it just nests list in each list.

Hope you enjoy some "good practice". :)
I just wanted to address your question precisely in my first try.

Comment: The downvotes were not mine to be clear, and I hope I didn't sound smug, I don't know if what OP wants to do is possible in a short one liner to be honest as I don't really want to try to decipher what it's supposed to do without an example :), it was just based on my experience with such code.

Comment: Of course :D I didn't assume it's yours, but it was only another factor that made me submit another, better (I believe) answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
for(i in 1:sample){
  hierdata[[i]] <- list()
  for(j in 1:10){
    code_j_init <- paste0("hierdata[[",i,"]]$Test_",j,"<- list()")
    eval(parse(text = code_j_init))
    hierdata[[i]][[j]] <- list(1,2,3)
  }
}
```

or

```
for(i in 1:sample){
  hierdata[[i]] <- list()
  names <- c()
  for(j in 1:10){
    hierdata[[i]][[j]] <- list(1,2,3)
    names <- c(names,paste0("Test_",j))
  }
  names(hierdata[[i]]) <- names
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an error "unexpected symbol in the code_j <- line. Is it because of the ,"i," ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice I misplaced comma, it should be before quotation mark

Comment: I mean after quotation :D sorry again

Comment: Interestingly, I'm now able to place the values calculated and put them in the assigned variables. However, the issue now is that the variables although created, they are not written into hierdata[[i]] for each i. Instead, they are created as separate variables in the values section in the global environment. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm able to write in now but only the last element. So if code_j above has a list of 10 values only the last value is written in. Any idea how to write into the dataframe all 10 values?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some sample code and the result I get. It should all be working if you implement it correctly. Minor change I made is using paste0 instead of paste

Comment: I misunderstood you, you're talking about the rowSums return value of course, then it needs a sligth modification, let me update you with some code in few minutes

Comment: The problem was paste0 took the last value to convert to string.
Now I've updated my answer and doing so I noticed that the more clear way would be the second option I've given there without eval. You can always assign names later so I wouldn't stick to naming it right away since it's really troublesome

Comment: The second option is working. However, I realized that it overwritten my previous data in hierdata. How can I append it rather that overwrites it.

Comment: We probably need something like hierdata[[i]]$[[j]]?

Comment: You just change first "for" loop to **for(i in length(hierdata) : length(hierdata)+sample)** and second "for" to **for(i in length(hierdata[[i]]) : (length(hierdata[[i]])+10)**